# nginx reverse proxy proxy_pass wildcard

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application running on port 4343. This is a single page app, so hitting `http://myApp:4343` will dynamically redirect me to somewhere like `http://myApp:4343/#/pageOne`.

Both the `nginx` container and the `myApp` container are running on the same docker network so can resolve via container name.

I'm trying to proxy this via nginx with:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location /myApp {
    proxy_pass http://myApp:4343
  }
}
```

How do I wildcard the rule?

Comment: You need to add trailing slashes. `/myApp/` and `http://myApp:4343/`

Comment: Legend! So simple :) :D